# Use selenium on ExtensionInstallForcelist chrome extension (extension installed via registry)

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I want to use selenium on some chrome extension. when I install the extension manually from store all works fine. But if I install the same extension via registry (ExtensionInstallForcelist) then I get some error while using selenium.

here my code:

```
//close all chrome instances
Process[] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (Process p in chromeInstances)
    p.Kill();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None;
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(webdriverPath, options); //<-Add your path
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome-extension://nofdpbenickbjghcdhapegiimmdinblo/Options.html");

//error here
IWebElement serverTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("server-adr-txt"));
```

The error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
> (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)'

Comment: Installing via policy probably takes some time so try adding a timeout.

Comment: @wOxxOm The extension is already installed